# Invite facebook friends to view a website

Tags: php, facebook, api, hybridauth

I am working on a website that will include a lot of social sharing etc. We are using HybridAuth library as it seems the best way forward for our project.

We want to offer users the ability to invite their facebook friends to view a specific page on our website. We don't want to use the javascript route as that would affect the look of the website as everything else works the same no matter what social network you are using.

What is the best way to invite users to view a website using the facebook api using php?